# Save view ids reference and filter it later

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-room, findviewbyid

Newby here :)
I'm thinking of a way to save selected Views ID as favorites. The views will be marked with icon and can be filtered in seperate tab in tabLayout.
All those ImageViews will be later used to click and give it more functionality

I did it with sharedPreferences by saving tag name that would be used as a KEY to save in sharedPref, The ImageView has the same tag as in Sound class, so I could later find it using findViewWithTag. First I was saving views id using getID() and findViewById but I've read the id's are generated at compile time and they can change later.

I have data class to store all relative data so if I would have many of those views I can iterate with .forEach insted of setting clickListeners one by one.

```
data class Sound(
    val imageBinding: ImageView,
    val imageFavBinding: LottieAnimationView,
    val tag: String,
    val group: String
)

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cloud"
    android:tag="image2"/>
```

Here I'm iterating every Sound in a list and either saving/removing sharedPref and hiding/showing icons

```
allImages.forEach { sound ->
        sound.imageBinding.setOnLongClickListener {
            val loadViewTag = sharedPreferences.getString(sound.tag, "")
            if (loadViewTag != "") {
                removeFromSharedPreferences(sound.tag)
                hideShowFavorites(sound)
            } else {
                val viewTag = it.tag.toString()
                addToSharedPreferences(sound.tag, viewTag)
                addFavoriteHeart(sound.imageFavBinding)
            }
            true
        }
    }

private fun removeFromSharedPreferences(tagName: String) {
    sharedPreferences.edit()
        .remove(tagName)
        .apply()
    val parentView = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.grid)
    val imageToLoad = parentView.findViewWithTag<ImageView>(tagName)
    if (binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition == 1) {
        imageToLoad.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    Snackbar.make(binding.tabLayout, "Removed From Favorites", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}

private fun addToSharedPreferences(tagName: String, viewTag: String) {
    sharedPreferences.edit()
        .putString(tagName, viewTag)
        .apply()
    Snackbar.make(binding.image1, "Saved To Favorites", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

It's working fine, but I think sharedPref isn't a good option for it since I can have many views to save and maybe I should use room db.
I could save my TAGs from data class and put it in db then retrieve it maybe as a list and add maybe add favorite: Boolean to data class and do something like this. So I can change the main list of allImages and later filter it by that favorite boolean

```
val favoriteList = listOf("image6", "image7", "image1", "image2")
favoriteList.forEach{favString ->
    allImages.forEach{sound ->
        if(sound.tag == favString) {
            sound.favorite = true
            sound.imageFavBinding.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

Sould I use findViewWithTag that way?
My main question: what is the best way to save favorites so I could end up with something like I did with sharedPref in **video bellow**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggyE4.gif

Thank You for any help with this problem.

Comment: users don't know what ImageViews are, so the fact that you're trying to save the ID of an ImageView probably means you're already approaching this incorrectly. users _could_ try to select their favorite _images_ though, which means that you need to find a way of knowing which image has been selected to be a favourite. if it is based on a certain index, then saves those indexes

Comment: @a_local_nobody The ImageViews is not relevant (here it works as a way for users to click and to set functionality later) it could be a button, switch or other item on which I'll later set visibility to gone or visible based on tabs and if it was marked with favorite. I'm setting user favorite by setting setOnLongClickListener on that view. Thank You for the input

Comment: your comment doesn't really change anything. i'm telling you that you should find a way of knowing which image was selected based on the image itself, whether you save that in an object or keep track of the index, because any solution you try to find by saving the view is a messy approach

Comment: hmm I get it, but finding a new way may be hard for me without some kind of example... I made it work that way and it took me a while. Do you know of any open source project that I may take it as example, I did look at github but couldn't find any... anyway I'll look for something more.